# Why does iterating over a hex array stop early?

Tags: c++, hex

### Problem and Code

I am working with code to take a screenshot on a Raspberry Pi.  Using some magic from the VC handler, I can take a screenshot and store it in memory with `calloc`.  I can use this to store the data in a file as a `ppm` image with the requisite header using:

```
void * image;
image = calloc(1, width * 3 * height);
// code to store data into *image
FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.ppm", "wb");
fprintf(fp, "P6\n%d %d\n255\n", width, height);
fwrite(image, width*3*height, 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

This successfully stores the data.  I can access it and view it normally.

However, if I instead try to inspect the data which are being put into the file for debugging purposes by printing:

```
int cnt = 0;
std::string imstr = (char *)image;
for (int i=0; i<(width*3*height); i++) {
    std::cout << (int)imstr[i] << "  " << cnt << std::endl;
    cnt += 1;
    }
```

I `segfault` early.  The numbers which are returned in the print make sense for the context (e.g. color values <255)

### Example Numbers

In the case of a 1280 x 768 x 3 image, my `cnt` stops at 64231.  The value it stops at doesn't seem to have any relation to the `sizeof` `char` or `int`.

I think I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't see it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are converting the `image` data to a `std::string` is wrong.  If the `image`'s raw data contains any `0x00` bytes then the `std::string` will be truncated, causing your loop to access out of bounds of the `std::string`.  And if the `image`'s raw data does not contain any `0x00` bytes then the `std::string` constructor will try to read past the bounds of the `image`'s allocated memory.

You need to take the `image`'s size into account when constructing the `std::string`, eg:

```cpp
size_t cnt = 0;
std::string imstr(static_cast<char*>(image), width*3*height);
for (size_t i = 0; i < imstr.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(imstr[i]) << "  " << cnt << std::endl;
    ++cnt;
}
```

Otherwise, simply don't convert the `image` to `std::string` at all.  You can iterate the `image`'s raw data directly instead, eg:

```cpp
size_t cnt = 0, imsize = width*3*height;
char *imdata = static_cast<char*>(image);
for (size_t i = 0; i < imsize; ++i) {
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(imdata[i]) << "  " << cnt << std::endl;
    ++cnt;
}
```

Comment: Ah, an incorrect sizing.  Bonus, I didn't know you could assign a size to string like that.  Thanks.

Comment: @WesH When using something you are not an expert on you should usually start by [reading up on it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) and make sure you know/understand all the details *before* using it.

Answer (score 4):

very probably you have at least a null character in `(char *)image`, so the `std::string` length is shorter than `width*3*height` due to its initialization because only the characters up to that first null character are used

use a `std::array` rather than a `std::string`initialized like that

Comment: Another possibility is that the image data *doesn't* contain a null character, and so the conversion to `std::string` tries to read past the bounds of the `image`'s allocated memory.  Also, you can't use `std::array` if you don't know the array size at compile-time. Use `std::vector` instead if the size is only known at runtime.

Comment: @RemyLebeau possibly, to use an array is probably a better choice to have a copy of the image

Comment: No null characters in the input data, but the array suggestion is good.  It might be useful for someone else experiencing a similar problem, but I think @RemyLebeau 's answer fits best.